# Why does my class respond to my global SEL variable only in Debug builds?

Tags: xcode, clang, objective-c++, clang++

I'm using Objective-C++ for a personal project and I found odd behavior with `SEL` variables at the global scope with an initializer. Consider this runnable Objective-C++ snippet:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject
-(void)closeWindow;
@end

@implementation Foo
-(void)closeWindow { puts("closeWindow called"); }
@end

static SEL globalSelector = @selector(closeWindow);

void printSelectorInfo(id target, SEL sel) {
    const char* name = sel_getName(sel);
    BOOL responds = [target respondsToSelector:sel];
    printf("selector=%p; name=%s; responds=%hhu\n", sel, name, responds);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        SEL localSelector = @selector(closeWindow);
        Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

        printSelectorInfo(foo, localSelector);
        printSelectorInfo(foo, globalSelector);

        [foo closeWindow];
        [foo performSelector:localSelector];
        [foo performSelector:globalSelector];
    }
}
```

In normal Objective-C, global variables must have a constant initializer as dictated by C, and therefore `static SEL globalSelector = @selector(closeWindow)` wouldn't be valid. This restriction is lifted in C++ and therefore in Objective-C++, and it compiles without issues.

This would be the expected output:

> selector=<some address>; name=closeWindow; responds=1
>   selector=<some address>; name=closeWindow; responds=1
>   closeWindow called [3 times]

And it's indeed what I get in Debug:

```
selector=0x7fff952d63a1; name=closeWindow; responds=1  
selector=0x7fff952d63a1; name=closeWindow; responds=1  
closeWindow called  
closeWindow called  
closeWindow called
```

However, things go wrong in Release:

```
selector=0x7fff952d63a1; name=closeWindow; responds=1
selector=0x100000eca; name=closeWindow; responds=0
closeWindow called
closeWindow called
2013-05-06 16:40:11.960 selectors[5048:303] *** NSForwarding: warning: selector (0x100000eca) for message 'closeWindow' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime (0x7fff952d63a1)-- abort
2013-05-06 16:40:11.964 selectors[5048:303] -[Foo closeWindow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100108240
2013-05-06 16:40:11.966 selectors[5048:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Foo closeWindow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100108240'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91116b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff904843f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff911ad40a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9110502e ___forwarding___ + 414
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91104e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   selectors                           0x0000000100000e14 main + 234
    6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff944a77e1 start + 0
    7   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Notice that now, while they still have the same name, the selectors don't have the same address, and `Foo` only responds to the selector in the local variable.

Interestingly enough, the issue seems to be name-sensitive. If I change the name of the method to, say, `foo`, it works correctly.

Am I missing something or relying on undefined behavior?

Comment: The point of selectors is that they are unique -- selectors with the same name should be equal. Selectors from different frameworks are unified when the program is loaded. Perhaps you somehow got the selector during a weird stage of initialization before this unifying is done?

Comment: @newacct, this possible, as I don't know in which relative order C++ initializers and the Objective-C runtime initialization happen (and I'm not sure it's a well-defined thing).

Comment: I also [filed a bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15922) for it, in case it's not just me doing stupid things.

Comment: I'd say that the runtime is being initialized either just before, or at the start of, `main()`, but that static SEL is being loaded far sooner.  If you tried making it a "singleton static variable", and initialized it in main,  you'd see that it works.

Comment: @CodaFi, the Clang guys said it was an issue in the version that specifically shipped with this release of Xcode and that it's fixed for the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no official Objective-C++ standard, I can't verify if this should be well-defined behavior or not. That said, I feel this is getting in the realm of compiler bugs, so I've been using this as a workaround:

```
/* reuse same heading as question */

static SEL globalSelector = @selector(closeWindow);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

        SEL localSelector = globalSelector;
        if (![foo respondsToSelector:localSelector])
        {
            localSelector = sel_getUID(sel_getName(localSelector));
        }

        [foo performSelector:localSelector];
    }
}
```

[The guys at LLVM confirm that this is a bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15922#c3) with the version of Clang that ships with Xcode 4.6.2 and that it will be fixed with the next release:

> You have hit a bug with this version of Xcode. I can confirm that the
>   bug has been fixed in next release of Xcode. In next release and with
>   -Os, printSelectorInfo is all inlined and no call is made to it. What you are noticing with -Os is some kind of tail call optimization of
>   printSelectorInfo which should be immaterial  to the bug you are
>   noticing.

Answer (score -1):

Complied selectors (SEL) are not function pointers they are objects that identify method names.

**objc.h**

```
typedef struct objc_selector    *SEL;
```

**Apple's Docs**

> Methods and Selectors
>
> > Compiled selectors identify method names, not method implementations. The display method for one class, for example, has the same selector as display methods defined in other classes. This is essential for polymorphism and dynamic binding; it lets you send the same message to receivers belonging to different classes. If there were one selector per method implementation, a message would be no different from a function call.
> >
> > A class method and an instance method with the same name are assigned the same selector. However, because of their separate domains, there’s no confusion between the two. A class could define a display class method in addition to a display instance method.

When I added the above example to my sample app line does not compile:

```
static SEL globalSelector = @selector(closeWindow);
    error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

I also get the warning

```
[foo performSelector:localSelector];
    warning: performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown
```

I do not get any warnings for

```
[foo performSelector:@selector(closeWindow)];
```

My understanding is that @selector(closeWindow) is a compile time directive identifying closeWindow as a selector but the lookup and creation on the objc_selector struct is done at run time. Where C++ is by default statically linked (and faster), Objective-C is dynamic.

**Interesting Tidbits**

http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html

> [target doMethodWith:var1]; gets translated into objc_msgSend(target,@selector(doMethodWith:),var1); by the compiler

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/

> Obviously, objc_msgSend() is called 10s of millions of times simply booting the system and launching some apps. Thus, every cycle counts and, no surprise, objc_msgSend() is written in hand tuned assembly.
>
> objc_msgSend() is designed to dynamically determine the implementation of a method — the function pointer that is the IMP tied to the selector on the targeted instance — without changing any of the caller/callee state. This enables a tail-call optimization that allows objc_msgSend() to jump [JMP] directly to the implementation of a method. This is also the reason why you don’t see objc_msgSend() in backtraces save for when a crash occurs in objc_msgSend()

Comment: How does that explain why `performSelector:` works with `localSelector` but not `globalSelector`, and only in release mode?

Comment: The reason you get a compile-time error is that you're not compiling the file as Objective-C++. If you use the `.mm` extension instead, the error will go away and the program will run. This is explicitly mentioned at the paragraph right after the code snippet in my question.

Comment: But is it a good thing (the code in question is Objective-C). Is the error still valid but that type of error detection is disabled for Objective-C++ because you can statically link C++ code. This is Objective-C is it doing a bad thing (setting globalSelector to garbage).

Comment: No, the code in this question is __not__ Objective-C. It's __Objective-C++__, and only compiles when used as such. In C++, it __is__ legal to initialize global variables with arbitrarily complex expressions. This global selector is __not__ garbage, as `sel_getName(globalSelector)` returns the correct name. The problem is that even though it's fine, `respondsToSelector:` returns `NO` and `performSelector:` fails, but only in Release builds: debug builds work just fine.

Comment: My Bad, I thought it was Objective-C and C++ code that was compiled by an Objective-C++ compiler. Thanks